# Is there a working way to wait for an user to reply (in DMS) discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

is there  a working way to wait for an user to reply (in DMS), my bot is going to ask something and then it waits for the user to reply. I already tried this but it didn't work, can someone help me fixing it or show me a better way to do it.

```
    var author = interaction.user;
  if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;

    // Get the data entered by the user
    const user = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('scammerUSERInput');
    const id = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('scammerIDInput');
  const reason = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('reasonInput');
    console.log({ user, id, reason });
  interaction.reply("<:camera:1005890593458765918> **Provide image or video proofs, all the proofs must be attached to the same message.**")
  author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time']
  })
  .then(message => {
    message = interaction.first()
    if (message.content.toUpperCase() == 'test1' || message.content.toUpperCase() == 'Y') {
      author.send(`Deleted`)
    } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == '2' || message.content.toUpperCase() == 'N') {
      author.send(`Terminated`)
    } else {
      author.send(`Terminated: Invalid Response`)
    }
  })
  .catch(collected => {
      author.send('Timeout');
  });
```

Error:

```
Caught exception:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'awaitMessages')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the DM channel with the user first (because the channel most likely doesn't exist between the user and the bot yet). The Discord.js User object has a function called [`createDM()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.0.3/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) for that:

```
var dmChannel = interaction.user.createDM();
dmChannel.awaitMessages(filter, options).then(msg => {
    // do stuff
})
```